# Selecting 2 column in an Inner join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Below are my two tables :

[image]

I am trying to write a query that joins these 2 tables AND returns the **Source_Title** and **Destination_Title** for the **given Source ID** of Result Map table.

I have tried written the query, but I can only solve one part of the puzzle not the whole thing.

```
SELECT Title as SourceTitle 
FROM Result Map AS RM 
INNER JOIN Table_Result TR ON RM.SourceId = TR.Id
```

The above query gives me the title for the source, but not the Destination title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Benjamin.
If I understood you correctly, you want something like this:

```
SELECT TR1.Title AS SourceTitle, 
       TR2.Title AS DestinationTitle
FROM [Result Map] AS RM
INNER JOIN Table_Result TR1 ON RM.Source_Id=TR1.Id
INNER JOIN Table_Result TR2 ON tr2.Id=RM.destination_id;
```

The query will return

```
SourceTitle DestinationTitle
ABC         DEF
```

Comment: my explanation was not clear 100%, but the query gives me exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

First, don't worry it's not just you. This trips up newcomers to SQL all the time. I see it so often. It's almost an inevitable part of SQL learning.

I'll try to do it in words. George K has already answered with the suitable code.

The trick is to not think of Table_Result as {*a table from which you extract titles*}.

This inevitably leads to you writing:

```
…
FROM {results table}
INNER JOIN {Table with titles in}
  ON {a join for which you can't find the appropriate logic}
```

You need to think in terms of the function the table serves *in your context*. Which is twofold in your case. Title of source, and title of destination.

Which gives you a query looking more like:

```
…
FROM {result table}
INNER JOIN {table from which you will extract source title}
  ON {join which allows you to retrieve a source title}
INNER JOIN {table from which you will extract destination title}
  ON {join which allows you to retrieve a destination title}
```